Running an update() with parameters from df.to_dict() causes errors
I am attempting to implement a functionality whereby a table in a SQL Server database is updated as per the contents of a pandas dataframe.
I check for overlapping IDs in the database table and in the pandas df, and for those IDs attempt to use the sqlalchemy.update and sqlalchemy.bindparam features to update the records:

def update_table(engine, user_table, dataframe: pd.DataFrame):

    dataframe = dataframe.add_prefix("b_")

    stmt = (
        update(user_table)
        .where(
            user_table.c.ID == bindparam("b_ID")
        )
        .values(
            other_column_a=bindparam("b_other_column_a"),
            other_column_b=bindparam("b_other_column_b"),
            other_column_c=bindparam("b_other_column_c")
        )
    )

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(stmt, dataframe.to_dict(orient="records"))
        conn.commit()
        return result


def main():

# other lines here (engine has already been initialized using sqlalchemy.create_engine())

    # Find if there are any IDs to update
    ids_to_update = old_ids.intersection(new_ids)
    if isinstance(ids_to_update, set) & (len(ids_to_update) != 0):
        with engine.connect() as conn:

            meta_data = MetaData(schema="uesm")
            meta_data.reflect(bind=conn)
            user_table = meta_data.tables[f"uesm.{table_name}"]

            df_to_update = new_dataset[
                new_dataset[id_names[table_name]].isin(ids_to_update)
            ]

            result = update_table(engine, user_table, df_to_update)

            print(f"Updated {result.rowcount} records in table {table_name}.")

What could be going wrong here?
When I run the above code, the SQL statement generated by the sqlalchemy.update functionality as printed in the console looks correct:
[SQL: UPDATE schema_name.table_name SET other_column_a=?, other_column_b=?, other_column_c=? WHERE schema_name.table_name.[ID] = ?]

And the dictionary being provided to the statement execution with the data looks entirely correct too. The same data is able to be inserted into the same target table using pd.to_sql functionality without any issue.
However, I receive the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

FYI: None of the numeric values I am trying to pass in there are any bigger than 3 digits, and I am trying to pass them into a decimal(8,3) column.
In the comments I was requested for the DDL for the table:

    CREATE TABLE [schema_name].[table_name](
        [ID] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
        [valid_from] [date] NOT NULL,
        [valid_to] [date] NOT NULL,
        [column_A] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
        [column_B] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
        [column_C] [decimal](8, 3) NOT NULL,
        [column_D_flag] [char](1) NOT NULL,
        [column_E] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_table_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
     CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_UEBERGABESTELLE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [valid_from] ASC,
        [valid_to] ASC,
        [column_A] ASC,
        [column_B] ASC,
        [column_C] ASC,
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO


As well as an excerpt from the dictionary that is being given to the statement:

    dict = [
        {
            "b_ID": "AMAG_Ranshofen 110_110_1.0",
            "b_valid_from": Timestamp("2023-01-01 00:00:00"),
            "b_valid_to": Timestamp("2050-01-01 00:00:00"),
            "b_column_A": "AMAG",
            "b_column_B": "Ranshofen 110",
            "b_column_C": 110,
            "b_column_D_flag": 0,
            "b_column_E": nan,
        },
        {
            "b_ID": "EKW_Großraming 110_110_1.0",
            "b_valid_from": Timestamp("2023-01-01 00:00:00"),
            "b_valid_to": Timestamp("2050-01-01 00:00:00"),
            "b_column_A": "EKW",
            "b_column_B": "Großraming 110",
            "b_column_C": 110,
            "b_column_D_flag": 0,
            "b_column_E": nan,
        }
    ]

Could it be that the nans are making the issue? Those are, however, only present in a non-numeric column.

What's the DDL of the user_table?

Can you show us an example of the dict that contains the parameter values?

Hello @AlwaysLearning and Mr. Thompson. I have added the DDL as well a sample of the data in the body of the question above. Grateful for your help.

Solved it! It was an issue with the null values-- they need to be set as None and the pandas conversion to dictionary was setting them as nan.

The problem is that .to_dict() returns "null" values in float/decimal columns as nan instead of None.
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 1.23), (2, None), (3, 3.14), ], columns=["new_id", "new_d"])
>>> df
   new_id  new_d
0       1   1.23
1       2    NaN
2       3   3.14
>>> params = df.to_dict(orient="records")
>>> params
[{'new_id': 1, 'new_d': 1.23}, {'new_id': 2, 'new_d': nan}, {'new_id': 3, 'new_d': 3.14}]
>>> null_value = params[1]["new_d"]
>>> type(null_value)
<class 'float'>
>>> repr(null_value)
'nan'

A "quick and dirty" fix is to create the list of dict by dumping the DataFrame out to JSON and loading it back
>>> as_json = df.to_json(orient="records")
>>> as_json
'[{"new_id":1,"new_d":1.23},{"new_id":2,"new_d":null},{"new_id":3,"new_d":3.14}]'
>>> params = json.loads(as_json)
>>> params
[{'new_id': 1, 'new_d': 1.23}, {'new_id': 2, 'new_d': None}, {'new_id': 3, 'new_d': 3.14}]
>>> null_value = params[1]["new_d"]
>>> type(null_value)
<class 'NoneType'>

